# Parameter is not valid (New Bitmap)

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, .net-6.0

I am having issues with creating a new bitmap, here is the code to load my image:

```
        public static Bitmap LoadImage(string imageURL)
        {
            if (_cache.ContainsKey(imageURL))
            {
                return _cache[imageURL];
            }
            else
            {
                _cache.Add(imageURL, new Bitmap(imageURL)); <-- Exception is thrown here (Parameter is not valid)
                return _cache[imageURL];
            }
        }
```

And I call the LoadImage method like this:

```
ImageHandler.LoadImage(StartGrid, _posX, _posY);
```

The variable StartGrid contains the file path, like this:

```
private const string StartGrid = @".\Assets\Sections\track_section_startgrid.png";
```

Where _posX and _posY are just set to 300.

I have tried changing the file path, but that went without success. I have tried debugging the file location but that also didn't result in anything. When looking on StackOverflow I found some more questions regarding this issue, but I haven't found something that works for me.

What I also find weird (though I am not sure this is part of the issue) but in the Autos Menu when debugging the imageURL is `".\\Assets\\Sections\\track_section_startgrid.png"` so it adds a second pair of slashes, why is this?

I would love every bit of help :)

Comment: To be sure of the path I would insert a File.Exists(imageURL) check before relying on it.. Are you sure about those slashes? Maybe the file is a not-so-well-supported png-type??

Comment: @TaW Excuse me for the late reply, but the file path seems incorrect, since it says the image isn't found, when i throw a `FileNotFoundException`, is there a way I can see the full path?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You ought to see that, no? - Often it help to test the data by adding a FileOpen dialog and use it to pick the file. Then you get the real and true path. Sometimes a weird charcter in a path is hard to see/recognize but prevents one to open the file..